# Some column headers disappear from JQGrid in IE10 while using Horizontal and Vertical scroll bar

Tags: jqgrid, internet-explorer-10

I see some strange behaviour in jqGrid in IE10 Standard mode, specially when grid size is bigger. 
When I scroll using horizontal scroll bar to the right of the grid and then scroll up to see the column headers, they are not visible (blank).

Attaching screenshots. It happens with the jqgrid demo as well

Steps to reproduce :
1. Open the jqgrid in IE10 . http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html -> Frozen Cols Group Header (New) -> Frozen Column
2. Drag some of the columns to the right (increase the width of the columns using mouse).

1. Resize the window so that all column headers are not visible in the screen.
2. Use horizontal scroll bar to scroll to the right of the grid.
3. Use vertical scroll bar to move up to see the column headers.
4. You will see that some column headers are not visible.
5. Screenshot can be found @ http://postimg.org/image/u1wa4k3er/

Please let me know if anyone has come across this problem and have any suggestions ?